# jQuery accordion() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My jQuery accordion() is not working on my HTML paragraphs. Where did I go wrong?

**simple.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <h1>This is an According Example</h1>           
        </div>
        <div id="accordion">
            <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
            <div>
            <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
            </div>          
            <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>            
            <div>
            <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
            <div>
            <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myscript.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion();
};
```

Comment: I tried your code as supplied, though I added the window.load call in a separate script block and it worked as expected. You should put the accordion code into 'document ready' listener as the others have pointed out. Does it not work, or does it look odd - because without the CSS files, it will look odd, but still work.

Comment: Your code works just fine as-is - http://jsfiddle.net/twgjW/ . What's "not working"? Using `$(document).ready` is preferred, as it doesn't wait for external resources like images to load. It won't make that big of a difference, but you might as well be consistent since you're using jQuery.

Comment: +1 thanks for your replies. When I click on the links (e.g. Heading for first sentence) the sentence below the heading does not disappear or reappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <h1>This is an According Example</h1>           
    </div>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
        <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>          
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>            
        <div>
        <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
        <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And put this in the head tag

```
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

And see this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/z6MJN/)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: You are not including the jQuery UI CSS, also your scripts must be included your `<head>`. Use this:

```
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>$(document).ready(function(){ $( "#accordion" ).accordion(); });</script>
</head>
```

and remove the scripts from the bottom of your page.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxJW6/ (This doesn't mean much because your problem was with including jQuery+jQuery UI in your page)

Comment: Would the user that downvoted my post please let me know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```