# Why html components in http are not working in https

Tags: html, http, https

So i tried out others http [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6MJN/) from this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776225/jquery-accordion-not-working).

HTML

```
<div id="mainContent">
        <h1>This is an According Example</h1>           
    </div>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
        <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>          
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>            
        <div>
        <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
        <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
$("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

It does't work when the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6MJN/) is in https.

```
Same as above
```

This is exactly the same situation I am having when developing in my PC (latest Chrome, Windows 10), e.g. file:///C:/path/to/projectname/index.html (It is displaying https version). May I know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Chrome console explains the problem:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/z6MJN/show/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

and

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://fiddle.jshell.net/z6MJN/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[MDN explains very well the problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent).

> If the HTTPS page includes content retrieved through regular,
>   cleartext HTTP, then the connection is only partially encrypted: the
>   unencrypted content is accessible to sniffers and can be modified by
>   man-in-the-middle attackers, and therefore the connection is not
>   safeguarded anymore. When a webpage exhibits this behavior, it is
>   called a mixed content page.

You can use the syntax `//` rather than `http://` or `https://`, and the browser will use the current page protocol to load those links.

https://jsfiddle.net/g0s4rj77/1/

Comment: regarding the second part of my question, when developing without using localhost, e.g. link in browser is file:///C:/path/to/projectname/index.html, it shows the https version, do you know how to make it to be http version? Or its not because of that?

Comment: if you see the `file://` protocol, that is not localhost :) You should have a local webserver installed in your computer, and access it using `http://localhost` for example.